# How to remove menu in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Taxonomy Menu created two menus, which have not gone even after I disabled it.

If I go to :

> admin/build/menu-customize/navigation

there is one menu "Company by Category" with many submenues. When I click edit it takes me to:`admin/build/menu/item/738/edit`. But here only Save button is found. How can I delete it?

Comment: I have not used that module before, but the best solution would be to re-enable the module, use the module's administration pages to remove the menus, then disable it again. If it does not offer that option for some reason, you can strong-arm it if you are comfortable issuing database queries directly: DELETE FROM menu_custom WHERE menu_name = 'menu_name_here'; DELETE FROM menu_links WHERE menu_name = 'menu_name_here';         Replace 'menu_name_here' with the menu's machine name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taxonomy menus are generated automatically and can be configured in the taxonomy vocabulary settings.

You can disable any taxonomy menu here:
Administer › Content management › Taxonomy › (Choose the related vocabulary) › edit vocabulary › Taxonomy Menu › Menu location: = DISABLED =